# UPDATE...FROM in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have come to know that MySQL doesn't support `UPDATE...FROM`. What's the alternative to that?

Actually I am trying to convert a MS-SQL Server Stored procedure to MySQL Stored procedure, and I am stuck at this line where it does:

```
UPDATE LedgerTbl 
SET RunninTotal = RTotal = RunningTotal + (DEBIT-CREDIT) 
FROM LedgerTbl;
```

**Here is the complete SQL Server Stored procedure:**

```
DECLARE @LedgerTbl TABLE (PARTY_ID VARCHAR(100),VRDATE VARCHAR(200),
                          VRNOA VARCHAR(200),ETYPE VARCHAR(50),
                          DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(500),DEBIT DECIMAL,
                          CREDIT DECIMAL, RunningTotal decimal) 

DECLARE @RunningTotal decimal 

SET @RunningTotal = 0 

INSERT INTO @LedgerTbl 
SELECT PARTY_ID,VRDATE,DCNO VRNOA,ETYPE,DESCRIPTION,DEBIT,CREDIT, null 
FROM PLEDGER WHERE PARTY_ID=@partyId AND VRDATE BETWEEN @from AND @to 
ORDER BY VRDATE,ETYPE,VRNOA 

UPDATE @LedgerTbl 
SET @RunningTotal = RunningTotal = @RunningTotal + (DEBIT-CREDIT) 
FROM @LedgerTbl 

SELECT * FROM @LedgerTbl
```

**And here is the MySQL Stored procedure that I have transformed it to:**

```
DELIMETER//

CREATE PROCEDURE `Acc_Ledger` ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE RunningTotal DECIMAL(19,2);
    SET RunningTotal = 0;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE LedgerTbl (PARTY_ID VARCHAR(100),VRDATE VARCHAR(200),VRNOA VARCHAR(200),ETYPE VARCHAR(50),DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(500),DEBIT DECIMAL,RTotal decimal);
    INSERT INTO LedgerTbl 
    SELECT PARTY_ID,VRDATE,DCNO VRNOA,ETYPE,DESCRIPTION,DEBIT,CREDIT, null FROM PLEDGER WHERE PARTY_ID=17 AND VRDATE BETWEEN '2013/12/02' AND '2010/12/02' 
    ORDER BY VRDATE,ETYPE,VRNOA; 

    UPDATE LedgerTbl 
    SET RunninTotal = RTotal = RunningTotal + (DEBIT-CREDIT) 
    FROM LedgerTbl;

    SELECT * FROM LedgerTbl;
END//
DELIMETER;
```

Comment: Look over [the Mysql `UPDATE` syntax reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) MySQL doesn't have a `FROM` clause in `UPDATE`. The table spec comes after the `UPDATE` keyword, may include joins, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the `FROM` clause, but the fact that it uses variables to update a running total. This can be translated to MySQL like so:

```
SET @RunningTotal := 0;

UPDATE LedgerTbl 
   SET RTotal = (@RunningTotal := @RunningTotal + (DEBIT - CREDIT));
```

What this does is assign to the variable `@RunningTotal` the difference between `DEBIT` and `CREDIT` plus the existing value of the `@RunningTotal` variable. The result of that, which is the new value of `@RunningTotal` is then assigned to the `RTotal` column of your temporary table.

This isn't the best way to do this, but it is *a* way, and if your rows are ordered correctly (according to the primary key) this will work.

Note: the variables with `@` in front are MySQL user variables, as documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html. Be careful to name them something unique since they could conflict with variables elsewhere in the same connection.

Comment: Can I do this in MySQL? I think you are targetting MS-SQL Server as from the variables `@RunningTotal`... I need to achieve this in MySQL.

Comment: @KamranAhmed: MySQL supports session-local user variables prefixed with `@`. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html.

Comment: What about the declaration? Will the existing declaration work?

Comment: @KamranAhmed: assuming you are talking about the variable, no, you don't need the declaration. The `SET` at the top of my code snippet is the closest equivalent. User variables aren't declared and don't have scope.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, you can just use:

```
UPDATE LedgerTbl 
SET RunninTotal = RTotal = RunningTotal + (DEBIT-CREDIT)
```

No table specification using `FROM` is necessary, it's specified via `UPDATE`